# Listing block devices inside a Kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, block-device

I am writing a kernel module that lists block devices and their corresponding dev_t which I will use for tracing.

The following is the structure block_device

```
    struct block_device {
    dev_t           bd_dev;  /* not a kdev_t - it's a search key */
    int         bd_openers;
    struct inode *      bd_inode;   /* will die */
    struct super_block *    bd_super;
    struct mutex        bd_mutex;   /* open/close mutex */
    struct list_head    bd_inodes;
    void *          bd_claiming;
    void *          bd_holder;
    int         bd_holders;
    bool            bd_write_holder;
#ifdef CONFIG_SYSFS
    struct list_head    bd_holder_disks;
#endif
    struct block_device *   bd_contains;
    unsigned        bd_block_size;
    struct hd_struct *  bd_part;
    /* number of times partitions within this device have been opened. */
    unsigned        bd_part_count;
    int         bd_invalidated;
    struct gendisk *    bd_disk;
    struct request_queue *  bd_queue;
    struct list_head    bd_list;
............
};
```

bd_list is a linked list containing all block devices in the system. all_bdevs ( fs/block_dev.c ) is the head of the list but the problem that it's not exported.
Is there a way to iterate block devices inside a kernel module ?